# Thinking logically instead of Venn diagrams

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

I hit upon the following identity while reading the book *How to Prove*:
$$(A \cup B) \backslash B \subseteq A$$

Now if I solve this logically I can reduce this like this:
$$
\begin{gather*}
x \in (A \cup B) \backslash \ B \\
x \in (A \cup B) \land x \in \lnot\ B \\
(x \in A \lor x \in B) \land x \in \lnot\ B \\
x \in \lnot\ B \land (x \in A \lor x \in B) \\
x \in \lnot \ B \land x \in A
\end{gather*}
$$
The above reduction gives me the intiution that $(A \cup B) \backslash\ B$  is a
subset of $A$. But if I think in terms of Venn diagrams, I come up
with the following idea:
$$(A \cup B) \backslash B = A$$
How to think in these conditions? This fallacy has also been
explicity stated in the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that if $A\cap B = \varnothing$, then $$(A\cup B) \setminus B = A$$

But we cannot simply assume that $A\cap B$ is empty. That is, $A$ and $B$ need not be disjoint.

Informally, if A and B overlap, then removing all of $B$ from $A\cup B$ removes part of A, too. In this case, $(A\cup B)\setminus B \subsetneq A$.

---

As for your "logical" argument, you've done fine, assuming by $\lnot B$ you mean the complement of $B$. Otherwise we can argue as follows:

$$\begin{align} x \in (A \cup B) \setminus B &\iff [x \in (A\cup B)] \land (x \notin B)\\
&\iff [x \in A \lor x \in B] \land (x\notin B)\\
&\iff (x\in A \land x \notin B) \lor \underbrace{(x\in B \land x\notin B)}_{\text{false}}\\ 
&\iff x \in A \land x \notin B\\
&\implies x \in A\end{align}$$
$\therefore \; (A\cup B)\setminus B \subseteq A$.